# Python code not working: TypeError,'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, typeerror, init, callable

The following Python code gives out error :

> **TypeError: 'int' object is not callable.**

Can anyone help me out?

```
string = "This is a string, but I want to print it backwards"
stringLen = len(string)
newString = []
while stringLen >= 0:
    newString.append(string[stringLen])
    stringLen = stringLen - 1
result = ''.join(newString)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

No able to reproduce the error. However, you have an

> Index out of range error.

This is because the indentation starts at 0. So `string[stringLen]` is out of bound at the first iteration. To solve it, just shift it by one with a simple `-1` operation.

Also, because we are now going in backward direction, we should stop when the counter is strictly superior to 0. If you go up to `0`, you will print the first character (so restarting iterating).

Here the code:

```
string = "This is a string, but I want to print it backwards"
stringLen = len(string)
newString = []
while stringLen > 0:
    # Here string is shifted by 1
    newString.append(string[stringLen-1])
    stringLen = stringLen - 1
result = ''.join(newString)
print(result)
# sdrawkcab ti tnirp ot tnaw I tub ,gnirts a si sihT
```

You can check your output by just calling:

```
print(string[::-1])
# sdrawkcab ekil skool txet siht woh rednow I
```

Some explanations [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_howto_reverse_string.asp)

Hope that helps !

Answer (score 0):

you can  get the same result with this code :

```
string = "This is a string, but I want to print it backwards"
result=''.join(string[::-1])
print(result)
```

outbut:

```
sdrawkcab ti tnirp ot tnaw I tub ,gnirts a si sihT
```

Comment: Please, do not answer several times at the same question, put all your solutions in one answer.

Comment: @AlexandreB. in the first answer i correct the problem of the questioner then in this answer i give him a new approach that's more efficient

Comment: @JoelBerkeley this line in the link "The only situation where posting multiple answers to the same question may be appropriate is when each of the answers, on its own, could be a valid and complete answer to the question."that you send show that i can make more than one answer if they are independent